# Serialize list of objects

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, xml-deserialization

I need to serialize/deserialize some XML code and part of it looks like next example:

```
<CoordGeom>
    <Curve rot="cw" chord="830.754618036885" crvType="arc" delta="72.796763873948" dirEnd="283.177582669379" dirStart="355.974346543327" external="169.661846548051" length="889.38025007632" midOrd="136.562611151675" radius="699.999999998612" tangent="516.053996536113">
        <Start>4897794.2800513292 6491234.9390137056</Start>
        <Center>4897096.0071489429 6491185.7968343571</Center>
        <End>4897255.5861026254 6491867.3645547926</End>
        <PI>4897758.0514541129 6491749.7197593488</PI>
    </Curve>
    <Spiral length="109.418078418008" radiusEnd="INF" radiusStart="699.999999999025" rot="cw" spiType="clothoid" theta="4.477995782709" totalY="2.849307921907" totalX="109.351261203955" tanLong="72.968738862921" tanShort="36.493923980983">
        <Start>4897255.5861026254 6491867.3645547936</Start>
        <PI>4897220.0531303799 6491875.6840722272</PI>
        <End>4897147.9238984985 6491886.7208634559</End>
    </Spiral>
    <Spiral length="153.185309785019" radiusEnd="499.99999999993" radiusStart="INF" rot="ccw" spiType="clothoid" theta="8.776871734087" totalY="7.808812331497" totalX="152.826239431476" tanLong="102.249348442205" tanShort="51.176160975293">
        <Start>4897147.9238985004 6491886.7208634559</Start>
        <PI>4897046.8509311257 6491902.186455016</PI>
        <End>4896998.0370401107 6491917.5553683294</End>
    </Spiral>
    <Curve rot="ccw" chord="936.510896488672" crvType="arc" delta="138.94725576785" dirEnd="66.423714388543" dirStart="287.476458620693" external="925.970149937768" length="1212.543549877849" midOrd="324.680762068264" radius="499.999999999181" tangent="1335.436583485725">
        <Start>4896998.0370401107 6491917.5553683294</Start>
        <Center>4897148.1939981515 6492394.4755796343</Center>
        <End>4896948.2091376046 6492852.7397562303</End>
        <PI>4895724.243644949 6492318.6055583945</PI>
    </Curve>
</CoordGeom>
```

I've generated automatically classes using xsd.exe. Part of generated code looks like this:

```
public partial class CoordGeom
    {
        private List<object> _items;
        private List<Feature> _feature;
        private string _desc;
        private string _name;
        private stateType _state;
        private string _oID;

        public CoordGeom()
        {
            _feature = new List<Feature>();
            _items = new List<object>();
        }

       [XmlElementAttribute("Chain", typeof(Chain))]
       [XmlElementAttribute("Curve", typeof(Curve))]
       [XmlElementAttribute("IrregularLine", typeof(IrregularLine))]
       [XmlElementAttribute("Line", typeof(Line))]
       [XmlElementAttribute("Spiral", typeof(Spiral))]
        public List<object> Items
        {
            get { return this._items; }
            set { this._items = value; }
        }

        [XmlElement("Feature")]
        public List<Feature> Feature { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute()]
        public string desc { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute()]
        public string name { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute()]
        public stateType state { get; set; }

        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
        public string oID
        {
            get{ return this._oID; }
            set{ this._oID = value; }
        }
    }
```

And my code for deserialization look like this:

```
XmlSerializer mySerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(LandXML), new XmlRootAttribute(""));
TextReader myFileStream = new StreamReader("myFile.xml");
LandXML myObject = (LandXML)mySerializer.Deserialize(myFileStream);
var coordGeomItems = myObject.Alignments.Alignment[0].CoordGeom;
```

My problem is that, when I deserialize file, it is deserialized as list of items of type {LandXML.Curve}, {LandXML.Spiral} etc. and I don't know how to access their properties. It would be great if I can do this directly. Here is a screenshot:

[image: Debugging screenshot]

**EDIT 1**

Here is inital screen
[image]

then I have items:

[image]

When I unfold this

[image]

And this is at the top layer of object - it has some InnerXml, InnerText... If I want to achieve CoordGeom, there is a lot object.Item(i).ChildNodes.Item(j).ChildNodes...

And all of that is because in some lines, lists of objects are made like List as for CoordGeom

Comment: can't you do coordGeomItems.Items[0] , coordGeomItems  .Items[1] etc??

Comment: I'm slightly confused.  Where is LandXML defined?  Where is the Alignments property defined?  Seems like we're missing some key info.  Perhaps you mean to extract all of the similar types and perform operations on each like so: `coordGeom.Where(x => x is Curve).ToList()`?

Comment: @xDaevax It is defined on the upper levels, the code is too much long for forum (total generated code is >30k lines). It's not a problem with previous parts of it, and that's why I posted only this part.

Comment: @Viru I can, but it's not a way, cause I need a list of that objects just in that order as in original XML file, and I need to access theri properties as directly as can

Comment: @RadeTomović I got it.....problem here is your XML is not structured properly....Now let say in your XML you had Curves collection which has all Curve element and likewise for Spiral then your generated XML would have direct properties to access it...As it is not like that...CoordGem will contain collection of objects of type Curve and Spiral and you have to cast to specific type before you use it.....So is it possible to change your XML structure??

Comment: It is not, it's generated based on Schema from http://www.landxml.org/schema/LandXML-1.2/LandXML-1.2.xsd using VS add-in xsd2code.

Comment: @RadeTomović Check my answer....hope it heps

Comment: @RadeTomović your intial question stated that you wanted way to access elements in your generated class coordgeom....but now in your new screenshot problem seems to be that you can't access CoordGeom xml node directly and you have to travese a lot in your xml to get that...some I am confused...what is your problem mention clearly?

Comment: Ok, I will screen complete process and upload on some video service and provide a link and the files. Otherwise,  I can't explain whole thing. I'm really thankful for your help and sorry for waiting your time

Comment: I have to apologize to all, I can actually access properties, I had to fix some things and now whole code working, tnx to everyone

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because there are multiple allowed types, the `Items` collection is typed as object.  The simplest approach is to enumerate and cast each item:

```
foreach(var item in coordGeomItems.Items)
{
    var curve = item as Curve;
    if (curve != null)
    {
        // access curve properties here
    }

    var spiral = item as Spiral
    if (spiral != null)
    {
        // access spiral properties here
    }

    // ...
}
```

Comment: coordGeomItems is a list of elements (what I saw it's a list of XmlElement types) and I can't run this code cause all results are false. Problem is in a moment of creation List<object> where objects are not stored as Curve, Spiral etc but as {Element, Name = Curve"}

Comment: No, can you see {} around LandXML.Curve? Normal state would be LandXML.Curve without {}

Comment: I'm skeptical an `XmlElement` would somehow include a qualified class name in its debugger display, but I haven't tried it. I think you need to come up with a [mcve] that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: Yes, it has, Full structure is LandXML.Alignments.Alignment.CoordGeom, but whole xsd generated class file is too large, and I have similar to this problem at a few places within it. I'll upload 2 more screenshots

Comment: @RadeTomović I think you have completly misunderstood the Debugger display....what that display is telling you that you have object at index 0 of Items of type LandXml.Curve.....{} are not meant to be taken literally

Comment: As pointed out by @CharlesMager it is fully qualified class name

Comment: Yes, but still I can't access properties and it's tot LandXML.Curve object, otherwise I could get access to them :/

Comment: @RadeTomović I think you are confused way value in debugger display is shown for value type and reference type...your object of type LandXml.Curve at index 0 is of reference type...For reference type, item[0]  will show what type of object it holds at that locaiton NOT the value so you are seeing the type LandXml.Curve with {}...This is how the Visual studio shows it...it does NOT mean that value is "{LandXml.Curve}"...To access it, you have to read Items[0] and cast it to specific type as shown in answer...

Comment: @Viru I can provide whole code if it would help, with my test files

Answer (score 1):

You could build up a list of Curves and Spirals and access them using properties with custom getters:

```
class CoordGeom
{
    public List<object> Items;

    List<Curve> _curves;
    public List<Curve> Curves
    {
        get 
        { 
            return _curves ?? (_curves = Items
                .Where(item => item is Curve).Select(curve => (Curve)curve).ToList()); 
        }
    }
}
```

The null coalescing operator (??) will cause the Curves property to set and return the value of _curves as a list of curves if _curves is null. This basically causes it to initialize the list on the first get and on all subsequent gets it will return the already initialized list.

Comment: I can, but then I loose an order of them, and I need their order in a list. For Example: it is important if I have curve,spiral,curve or curve,curve, spiral

Answer (score 1):

As you cannot change the generated class nor the XML.The best possible approach would be to write an extension method.

```
public static List<Curve> GetCurves(this CoordGeom cg)
{
return cg.Items.OfType<Curve>().ToList();
}

public static List<Spiral> GetSpirals(this CoordGeom cg)
{
return cg.Items.OfType<Spiral>().ToList();
}
```

Once you do this, you can get items like this

```
var coordGeomItems = myObject.Alignments.Alignment[0].CoordGeom;
var curves = coordGeomItems.GetCurves();
var spirals = coordGeomItems.GetSpirals();
```

Comment: I need to maintain order of Curves and Spirals in a list of Objects :(